# Azure loadbalancer for two vms which are listening on same port number 8005. How to route traffic from frontend IP of loadbalancer?

Tags: azure

I have a special requirment. I created azure loadbalancer which has frontend IP 65.x.x.x, and two azure vms, already configured loadbalancer rules. Two azure vms applicatios are listening on port 8005. So i want to route traffic from azure loadbalancer. If i hit 65.x.x.x:8005, it should route route traffic to healthy vm. SO how to create security rules to open port.